# Store array output to comma separated list in bash scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, bash

I have taken input from user into array. But I need to use them as comma separated list. How can I do that? Input in my case is path like (/usr/tmp/). I appreciate your help and time. Thank you !

Example:

```
read "Number of subdirectories : " count
for i in $(seq 1 $count)
do
    read -e -p " Subdir : $i: " arr[$i]
done
```

Expected Result:

```
$var = {arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],......}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an array like this:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([1]="abc" [2]="def")'
```

You can display it in comma-separated format:

```
$ (IFS=,; echo "{${arr[*]}}")
{abc,def}
```

That output can be saved in a shell variable using *command substitution*:

```
$ var=$(IFS=,; echo "{${arr[*]}}")
$ echo "$var"
{abc,def}
```

Comment: Thanks @John. I tried but it's not working. I got an error like No such file or directory.

Comment: @Rock26 Which command produced an error?  Also please let me see the complete exact error message. (Don't retype: copy-and-paste it from you terminal to here.)

Comment: Sure../count_lines.sh: line 22: ={plugme/web/,plugme/modules/}: No such file or directory

Comment: Since I have not seen the file `count_lines.sh`, can show me what was on line 22 in that script?

Comment: $(IFS=,; echo "{${dir_exclude[*]}}")     <-- line 22, I am using another array name.

Comment: That command differs from what I showed in the answer.  What were you expecting that command to do?  It creates the comma-separated string and then asks the shell to find a program with that name, commas and all.  That can't be what you want.

Comment: I want to store it to some variable and then I need to use this variable/list to some another command.

Comment: @Rock26, if you want help with your script, include your script in the question. It is very difficult to diagnose things at this distance.

Comment: @Rock26 The command that I showed in the answer was `var=$(IFS=,; echo "{${arr[*]}}")`.  The command that you say you ran was `$(IFS=,; echo "{${dir_exclude[*]}}")`.  Those are two very different commands and they produce two very different results.